# Where is the 'basics package' described on p. 32 of "Programming Robots with ROS"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on page 34 of Morgan Quigley's book, *Programming Robots with ROS* and he says to make sure that the basics package is in your workspace. This is the first time he mentioned the package and doesn't give an explanation for itaa.  How do I find it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238046/where-is-the-%27basics-package%27-described-on-p.-32-of-%22programming-robots-with-ros%22/) by [tmulz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26368/tmulz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-06-26**:
What files does he mention are inside the package? It may help us to narrow down which package it was.

**Comment by [tmulz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26368/tmulz/) on 2016-06-28**:
He doesn't mentioned any files in the package. I'm supposed to run the command "rosrun basics topic_publisher.py" I made a new package and copied the code for topic_publisher.py into the package. When I run the command, I get an error: [rospack] Error: package 'basics' not found

**Comment by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) on 2016-06-28**:
In the command, `basics` is the name of the package. To make this work with your package, you need to substitute the name of your package for `basics`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After doing some research, I found the package on GitHub here: https://github.com/osrf/rosbook/tree/master
This repository contains all the code for the entire book, the part you are looking for is in the `/code/basics/` folder.
Hope that helps,
luketheduke

---

Originally posted by [luketheduke](https://answers.ros.org/users/20641/luketheduke/) with karma: 285 on 2016-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tmulz](https://answers.ros.org/users/26368/tmulz/) on 2016-06-29**:
Thank you!